# What is the most efficient way to get the first time a track was played via last.fm API

Tags: python, api, last.fm

I am trying to get the first time a track was played from the last.fm API. The only way I can figure out how to get the first time a given track was played is to iterate through all of the instances of the method user.getRecentTracks. This is extremely inefficient. Does anyone else have another suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only other way the API allows you to get this data is to use the [`user.getArtistTracks`](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getArtistTracks) resource, which allows you to get all a user's track plays, filtered by specific artist.

The API returns a list of tracks that you can parse and filter to get the track you want, and you can retrieve the history of scrobbles for that track.

Here's an example using the [`Python pylast last.fm API wrapper`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylast/):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pylast

API_KEY = 'API-KEY-HERE'
API_SECRET = 'API-SECRET-HERE'

username = 'your-user-to-authenticate'
password_hash = pylast.md5('your-password')

# Specfy artist and track name here
artist_name = 'Saori@destiny'
track_name = 'GAMBA JAPAN'

# Authenticate and get a session to last.fm (we're using standalone auth)
client = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret = API_SECRET,
                              username = username, password_hash = password_hash)

# Get an object representing a specific user
user = client.get_user(username)

# Call get_artist_tracks to retrieve all tracks a user
# has played from a specific artist and filter out all
# playbacks that aren't your track
track_scrobbles = [x for x in user.get_artist_tracks(artist_name)
                   if x.track.title.lower() == track_name.lower()]

# It just so happens that the API returns things in reverse chronological order
# of playtimes (most recent plays first), so you can just take the last item
# in the scrobbled list for the track you want
first_played = track_scrobbles[-1]

# first_played is of type PlayedTrack, which is a named tuple in the lastpy lib

print("You first played {0} by artist {1} on {2}".format(first_played.track.title,
                                                         first_played.track.artist,
                                                         first_played.playback_date))
```